# String Split using SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio v17.

I have a string:

```
Primary sector: General Industries Group Sub-sector: Chemicals (incl. agri businesses) Tier:6
```

Expected Output

Primary_Sector
General Industries Group

Sub_Sector
 Chemicals

I want to compute two new variables - `Primary_Sector` and `Sub_Sector` that contains `General Industries Group` and `Chemicals` respectively. Do you know what would be the best technique to extrapolate the text and how I would do it?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?  Note that the version of SQL Server and the version of SQL Server Management Studio can be different.  Also do you only want to parse this particular string, or are you looking for something more generic over a larger database?  Double also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, the server is 2017 version

Comment: I'm looking for something more generic across a larger database but if I can understand how to transform the above example string I should be able to figure it out on a bigger scale. Been trying substring and charindex. Doesn't seem to clean the data in the example.

Comment: pls add your expected output

Comment: Unless you have a separator in your string, a Split will be of no help: you can neither split by space nor by colon nor by anything else. However, you could try to use the standard CHARINDEX('Primary sector:')  and SUBSTRING is from the colon to the CHARINDEX(Sub-sector:).

Comment: can you edit your question and show us exact how you want to see the expected results

Comment: Expected output is Primary_Sector = "General Industries Group" and Sub_Sector = "Chemicals"

Comment: can you edit your question and put the expected output there, not in the comments

Comment: @GuidoG  What are you guys all talking about?  The expected output has been in the question from the start...?

Comment: Why do you not want to include `(incl. agri businesses)` in your `Sub_Sector` value?  Will all possible output values need to ignore text within parentheses?  I am also assuming `Tier` is a different value that you are simply ignoring in this particular string?

Comment: @iamdave Good thing he put the expected outcome in the question, else we would not know that the value inside parentheses should be ignored

Comment: @GuidoG  We *do not* know that *all* values inside parentheses should be ignored.  Providing an answer here that looks for an opening parenthesis to mark the end of the `Sub_Sector` value will obviously not work where there are `Sub_Select` values that don't contain one, hence my request for further clarification.

Comment: @iamdave Agreed, and this is why knowing exact how the output should look like can help much in finding an answer

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty simple via Substring:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(100) = 'Primary sector: General Industries Group Sub-sector: Chemicals (incl. agri businesses) Tier:6';

DECLARE @l INT = LEN(@x);
DECLARE @iTier INT = CHARINDEX('Tier:', @x)
DECLARE @iSubSector INT = CHARINDEX('Sub-sector:', @x)
DECLARE @iPrimarySector INT = CHARINDEX('Primary sector:', @x)

SELECT 'Tier = ' +  SUBSTRING(@x, @iTier+5, @l-(@iTier+5)+1)
SELECT 'SubSector = ' + SUBSTRING(@x, @iSubSector+11, @iTier-(@iSubSector+11))
SELECT 'PrimarySector = ' + SUBSTRING(@x, @iPrimarySector+15, @iSubSector-(@iPrimarySector+15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Tabl AS TABLE(data nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO @Tabl
SELECT 'Primary sector: General Industries Group Sub-sector: Chemicals (incl. agri businesses) Tier:6'

SELECT  data,
        [Primary sector],
        SUBSTRING([Sub-sector],1,CHARINDEX(')',[Sub-sector]))AS [Sub-sector],
        Tier 
FROM
(
SELECT data,
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(data,0,CHARINDEX('Sub-sector:',data)),':',' = ') AS [Primary sector],
        REPLACE(SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX('Sub-sector:',data),LEN(data)),':',' = ') AS [Sub-sector]
        ,RIGHt(data,LEn('Tier:')+1) AS [Tier]
 FROM @Tabl
 )dt
```

Demo Result:http://rextester.com/ARPH77432